# fall-through switch for executing a sequence of steps

Tags: design, design-patterns, coding-style, clean-code, switch-statement

My program needs to execute a sequence of steps from start to end. But based on different input the start point will vary, e.g, some will run from the first step to end, some will run from the 2nd step to the end, some will run from the 3rd to the end, etc.

I just need a simple design, currently I use fall-through switch like this:

```
switch (step) {
case 1:
     //do the 1st step
     //fall through, so no break here
case 2:
    //do the 2nd step
    //fall through
case 3:
    //do the 3rd step
    //fall through
...
}
```

It works but the fall through code always makes me uncomfortable. Is there a better and simple way to do it ?

Comment: You shouldn't crosspost. I believe your question makes sense on this website, so if I were you, I would delete the question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK I deleted it on SO and update my question here as well. Thanks.

Comment: Is the data required for each step the same? Can you extract each step into its own function with the same arguments and return type?

Comment: no that is why the array solution may not apply to my case

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the language you are using, you can create a array of functions and use `step` as your start point for looping over them. Something like:

```
var functions = function[]
{
    step1,
    step2,
    step3,
    …
}

foreach (var index = step-1; index <= function.count; index++)
{
    functions[index]();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, currently I am using javascript but I think your solution applies to c/c++ too. Thanks!

Comment: This would be the ideal solution, as long as the input and output of each function is the same.

Answer (score 4):

The way you are doing it is perfectly good and simple; it's what fallthrough is for in the first place. If it makes you more comfortable, you can add a comment explaining what you are doing (so that somebody else doesn't take half an hour to understand why it's that way).